# Lithium PHP global variables

Tags: php, variables, global, lithium

I have looked all over the place, but still cant figure out how to set a global variable in PHP (Lithium framework).

My goal is to make the server root always accessible everywhere, without having to write this code everytime, to make my app independent of the hostname it is running on :

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Please don't tell me to just use absolute or relative paths, as I have tried everything that way, and it is simply too messy (besides not working most of the time).

Comment: Custom superglobals are not possible in PHP (not without [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.configuration.php), anyway). As a work around I usually start a session (regardless of whether I actually need one) so you can write data to the `$_SESSION` array (beware the request concurrency hole, always use [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) at the earliest possible opportunity in every script). I have also seen people use `$_ENV`, but it is not designed for that purpose so doesn't come recommended - YMMV.

Comment: I believe that this should be done somewhere in the boostrap part of the lithium framework, so that the code is not executed every time someone requests a page. Only on the first request should the value be calculated... Still waiting for an answer, maybe ill just stick to runkit.

Comment: Runkit is not likely to be available everywhere (if anywhere). If you want to calculate the value once the first time the user arives at the site, it sounds like an ideal candidate for sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your code above is in a template.  So you can use `$this->request()->to('url')` to get the current url.  Or from a controller, it would be `$this->request->to('url')`.  You can also pass `'absolute' => true` to the options for `Router::match`.  Unfortunately, the html link helper - i.e. `$this->html->link(...)` - doesn't pass the `'absolute' => true` option through to the `Router::match` but you can call `$this->url()` which is passed through to `Router::match`.  So it would be `$this->url('/relative/url', array('absolute' => true))`.

See the [docs for Router::match](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/net/http/Router%3a%3amatch)

The `Request` object also provides access to things like http host and request uri.  See the [docs for `Request::env()`](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/action/Request%3a%3aenv)

But, to your original point about global vars, I think the [Environment](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/core/Environment) class should be used for this.  You can put arbitrary data in it -- and even set it in your bootstrap to have different values for different environments (i.e. dev vs. staging vs. production).

Comment: Yeah, this seems like the proper way to do it, framework wise! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but use relative paths and use the link generator helper, which *won't* get what you're trying to do wrong.

See [the docs](http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/template/helper/Html%3a%3alink%28%29).

Comment: Not always the way. For example, RFCs state that `Location:` headers should always contain a full URL and not a relative path. Most browsers will handle relative paths but since it is breaking the standard, this behaviour should not be relied upon.